# How I can pull data from a Cucumber table in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, bdd, cucumberjs, wdio-v6

I want to perform a test case where I'm trying to login with different credentials and check the error message. How this can be done in Cucumber?

```
Feature: Login

Login Test Suite

Background: 
  Given I'm on the login page

Scenario: 01. Should not be able to login with invalid cred
When I log in with "username" and "password"
    |  username   | password | ExpectedError                     |
    |    asdasd   | anything | Invalid credentials specified     |
    |             | anything | Please specify a username         |
    |    asdasd   |          | Please specify a password         |
    |             |          | No username or password specified |
Then An error msg should appear
```

Here's where I want to pass the two args, username and password:

```
When('I log in with (string) and (string)', (username,password) => {
    p.loginWith(username, password)
})
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want one scenario that logs in multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a [Scenario Outline](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#scenario-outline). You will need to rephrase each step, and the data table will get moved to an "Examples" table:

```
Feature: Login
  Login Test Suite

Background: 
  Given I'm on the login page

Scenario Outline: 01. Should not be able to login with invalid cred
  When I log in with "<username>" and "<password>"
  Then the "<ExpectedError>" error msg should appear

Examples:
  | username | password | ExpectedError                     |
  | asdasd   | anything | Invalid credentials specified     |
  |          | anything | Please specify a username         |
  | asdasd   |          | Please specify a password         |
  |          |          | No username or password specified |
```

The scenario will get executed once for each row in the Examples table. The `<...>` tokens in the steps allow you to reference a value in one of the example table columns.

Your `Then` step needs to be rephrased to pass the expected validation error. It's step definition is pretty simple, and I'll leave the implementation up to you. Here is the stub:

```
Then('the (string) error msg should appear', (expectedError) => {
  // TODO: Make assertion
});
```

Comment: how I will be passing the two args in the function ins that case
should it be like that 

When(/^I log in with '(.*)' and '(.*)'$/, (username,password) => {
    p.fillUserName(username,password)
    return this;
})

Comment: @amrkamel: yes, your individual steps will not be dealing with data tables. Your individual steps will only deal with  strings.

Comment: great thanks man, I would like to ask you something else if you don't mind 
I there a way to add-hook (beforeAll) to be run once and before all specific set of scenario 

let's say I have 4 scenarios 2 of them needs a specific method to be run once before these specific two, I have tried to use before hook with tags but I find it's  equal to beforeEach, which means its not running only once

Comment: @amrkamel Sounds like you have another question! Post it as a new question and you'll get more answers.